# How to write excel file within the python code into a server location which is hosted on IIS Server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, iis

I was working on a web based platform product, my python Code is hosted on IIS Server. I need to Export my df as an excel in to the path or you can say url path.

```
my_url_path = http//10.6.36:8075/products/items/Aug
```

I tried:

```
df.to_excel(my_url_path+'/'+'df.xlsx, index=False)
```

Comment: A bit more explaination of what your desired outcome is, and what errors you are getting would help get this question answered.

Comment: @jeffrey Suppose there is a df which I am processing, after it get processed I need to Export that df in to a folder as an excel file, this folder path is "http//10.6.36:8075/products/items/Aug" which is at my vm. The problem is I don't know how to export files taking url path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write/export something to other windows machines, we need to do some stuff like impersonate.
Here are some code snippets to demonstrate this feature.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8
Simply speaking, we need to enable impersonating the users on the remote user so that can write a file with that Window identity. If the IIS server and the remote file server are the same machines, it is enough to use the relative address to fill the `Path` parameter.
In python, Python’s Win32 access to help to simplify providing privileged access.
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/Windows_NT_Security_.2d.2d_Impersonation.html
https://codingsimple.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/python-for-windows-logon-and-run-as-different-user/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.